# C# - Rotating polygon randomly

Tags: c#, winforms, polygon

I'm trying to rotate polygon randomly using timer. I got to draw regular polygons and rotate it to one direction. But I'm not sure about how to rotate polygon to random direction using angle or timer interval.

My Code is below:

```
int sides = 5;
Graphics g = e.Graphics;
nPoints = CalculateVertices(sides, radius, angle, center);

g.DrawPolygon(navypen, nPoints);
g.FillPolygon(BlueBrush, nPoints);
Point center = new Point(ClientSize.Width / 2, ClientSize.Height / 2);

for(int i = 0; i < sides; i++) {
     g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Navy), center.X, center.Y, nPoints[i].X, nPoints[i].Y);

}

private PointF[] CalculateVertices(int sides, int radius, float startingAngle, Point center)
{
    if (sides < 3) {
        sides = 3;
    }

    List<PointF> points = new List<PointF>();
    float step = 360.0f / sides;

    float angle = startingAngle; //starting angle
    for (double i = startingAngle; i < startingAngle + 360.0; i += step) //go in a circle
    {
        points.Add(DegreesToXY(angle, radius, center));
        angle += step;
    }

    return points.ToArray();
}

private PointF DegreesToXY(float degrees, float radius, Point origin)
{
    PointF xy = new PointF();
    double radians = degrees * Math.PI / 180.0;

    xy.X = (int)(Math.Cos(radians) * radius + origin.X);
    xy.Y = (int)(Math.Sin(-radians) * radius + origin.Y);

    return xy;
}

private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e){
    angle += 1;
    angle_tri -= 1;
    Invalidate();
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking for help on? Timers? generating random numbers? Rotating polygons? Its not exactly clear what your problem is at the moment. And to be clear the reason I am asking this is because your question should be focused on one specific problem, not a wider issue with a lot of other issues.

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you rotate the Graphics object instead. Move to the rotation center with Graphics.TranslateTransform, then rotate with Graphics.RotateTransform, move  back and draw the polygon. Then ResetTranform.. - You can also stuff the points into a GraphicsPath and Transform it with a rotated matrix..

Comment: @Taw Can I do this with random timer interval without changing angle?

Comment: Random? yes, Random timer interval? yes. Without changing the angle? No, each paint event starts with an unrotated graphics object. Store the angle at class (most likely Form) level and modify in the Tick. There you can also change the Interval..

Comment: @TaW sorry, but can you give me an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of drawing a list of points rotated with varying speeds, both angular and and timing..:

[image]

First a few variables:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
float angle = 0f;
List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
```

Then a `Tick` with varying speed and a varying angle:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    angle += rnd.Next(0, 33)/ 10f;
    timer1.Interval = rnd.Next(100) + 15;
    pictureBox5.Invalidate();
}
```

Here is the `Paint` event of a `PictureBox`, which is `DoubleBuffered`, so it won't flicker..:

```
private void pictureBox5_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (points.Count > 1)
    {
        Point center = new Point(
            (points.Select(x => x.X).Max() + points.Select(x => x.X).Min()) / 2,
            (points.Select(x => x.Y).Max() + points.Select(x => x.Y).Min()) / 2);

        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(center.X, center.Y);
        e.Graphics.RotateTransform(angle);
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(-center.X, -center.Y);
        e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(Pens.DarkGreen, points.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Note that due to the weird speed changes this is anything but smooth; you would have to find better algorithms for them than mere randomness..